# Mapping List[Int] to Chars

Tags: scala

I tried to `map` over a `List[Int]`:

```
List(1,2,3).map(_.toChar)
>> List[Char] = List(?, ?, ?)
```

But I see a bunch of `?`s.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

You want `List(1,2,3).map(_.toString.head)`.  `Int.toChar` turns the *ascii* value into its corresponding `Char`.  For example:

```
(80).toChar   // P
```

The characters for ascii values 1,2,3 are [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) that can't be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `java.lang.Character.forDigit(digit: Int, radix: Int)`:

```
List(1,2,3).map(i => Character.forDigit(i, 10))
```